# How to color excel cells using pandas style based on their match?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, colors

I need to set a background color to cells that have expressions that match with each other, that is, considering that the expression "e1" in column col1 matches with the expression "e2" in column col2, these two cells need to receive a new background color.

```
def check_match(c1, c2):
  if c1 == "e1" and c2 == "e2":
    return True
  else:
    return False


styled = (df.style.applymap(lambda v: 'background-color: %s' % 'red' if checkmatch(v['col1'],v['col2']) else '', subset=['col1','col2']))
```

however, when using the subset option in `applymap` I cannot get the columns separately.

I have also tried using `apply`, but with this option, I got an error like if the shape return of the `check_match` function was different from the dataframe *df*

Comment: this question needs more detail and in particular a clarity between what is meant by comparing an expression in a column with and expression in another column. is this element wise comparison measured over a whole column?

Comment: your function wont work because applymap takes a single cell and should return a string, your function is not properly connected with the elements your want to compare.